# uninitialized constant RecieversController::TellstickR

Tags: ruby, rails-api

I'm having trouble getting my rails-api project recognizing a gem i have installed.
The title of this post says what im getting as an error.

I'm trying to make the most minimalistic project to make this work.

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'rails-api'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'tellstickr', '~> 0.0.1'
```

PS. I only added the last line to this file.

Routes.rb:

```
ProjectName::Application.routes.draw do

    resources :recievers

    root :to => 'recievers#index'
end
```

Recievers_controller.rb:

```
require 'tellstickr'

class RecieversController < ApplicationController

    def index
        list = TellstickR::Device.discover
        item = list.first
        item.on
    end
end
```

I used the latest RubyInstaller so i problably have the latest stable version of ruby. Ran gem install rails after that. I have searched and gone thru some guides on Ruby and RoR and i still can't seem to figure this out. Why can't it recognize the tellstickr gem? I hope i have provided enough info for some ruby-guru to figure this out. I have also run bundle install.

When going to

```
http://192.168.0.17:3000/
```

after running 'rails s' to start the webserver this is what i get:

```
NameError in RecieversController#index
uninitialized constant RecieversController::TellstickR

Extracted source (around line #11):

def index
    list = TellstickR::Device.discover     #.#.#.#.# line 11 #.#.#.#.#
    item = list.first
    item.on
end
```

I need help since i am beginner at this! :)

//Daniel

Comment: You need a capital S as in TellStickR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
TellStickR::Device.discover
```

Capital T, capital S, capital R